# Priority queue in Java so each producer gets one turn at a time

Tags: java, queue

If I have multiple users (not countable), who each are putting work items
on a queue, how can I implement a queue so that each user gets one turn at
a time?

For example, if I have users A B C, and have a queue like [A A B C D A A B
C A], I'd want it to be processed in this order [A B C D A B C A A]

This would be easy to implement but what if more work comes in while
processing the current queue elements. So:

- Start with queue: [A A B C D A A B C A]
- Process the queue: A B C D
- Queue is now: [A A A B C A]
- More work is added: [A A A B C A D E A B C]
- Process the queue A B C D E

etc

I do not know ahead of time how many different possible users there will
be, so cannot simply iterate through a predefined list of users and do work
(if there is any) for each. I don't care about the order that each user's
work gets processed, as long as no user gets two units work while other
users have work waiting.

Comment: The terminology of this question is a bit confusing. This isn't a queue at all – it's not FIFO and it's not a priority queue. It's something entirely different. And it's also somewhat confusing that you're talking about each _producer_ getting one turn at a time.

Comment: @MattBall Sorry for the terminology, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: You just need a circular buffer of queues, one queue per producer. Easy.

Comment: @EJP how do you create a circular buffer for an uncountable number of producers?

Comment: @EJP I don't think this is feasible if I have 1000s of users and they are not submitting work all the time. I also don't know the users before I begin.

Comment: I don't think this is so hard. Just some kind of thread-safe linked list that you process sequentially and when you get to the end, start again at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the way I would solve this problem off the top of my head would be to have a hashmap where the different users (ie A, B, C, D etc) would be the keys and the value associated with each key would be the number of "turns" they have left. Then you can simply iterate through the map, check if the "user" has any more "turns" left, if they do, process it, if they don't, go to the next "user".

edit: Use an array protected by mutex locks or some threadsafe ordered object to hold every user being processed. Also add the users to a concurrenthashmap as keys where the value associated with each key is the number of steps until they are done. Have another variable which holds the current position on the list.

Comment: As I stated, I unfortunately do not know ahead of time all the users. New users could request work in the middle of processinf the queue as well. Having to continually find all the users in the queue could work but I'd have to do this whenever I add or remove something from the queue.

Comment: My solution still works, all you need to do is remember the current position in the "queue". Have an array with all of the different users and a list. Have some shared variable that holds your position in  the "queue". Once you process the "step", move to the next position in the list and subtract a step from the hashmap. The hashmap and array would need to be protected by locks though and you wouldn't be able to use an iterator like I originally suggested.